# R collapse multiple rows into 1 row using specific function to each column

Tags: r, data.table

consider next dataset:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
col_a <- c(123,56,87,987,1003,10)
col_b <- c(17,234,20,88,765,69)
col_c <- c(45,90,543,NA,1,543)
df <- data.frame(id,col_a,col_b,col_c)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

Using grouping by id I need to apply for each column different function:
for example: min for col_a, median for col_b and max for col_c, to generate next result:

```
id  col_a col_b col_c
1   56    20   543
2   10    88   543
```

Need to complete solution like this:

```
df[, lapply(.SD, ???), by=id]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map` to apply each of the functions to the corresponding columns grouped by 'id'

```
df[, Map(function(x,y) get(x)(y, na.rm = TRUE), 
       setNames(c('min', 'median', 'max'),names(.SD)), .SD), by = id]
#   id col_a col_b col_c
#1:  1    56    20   543
#2:  2    10    88   543
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `tidyverse` you could do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(col_a = min(col_a),
         col_b = median(col_b),
         col_c = max(col_c, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id col_a col_b col_c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    56    20   543
2     2    10    88   543
```