# Calculating a weighted mean in data.table in R varying weights

Tags: r, data.table

My question relates to this previously asked question:
[Calculating a weighted mean using data.table in R with weights in one of the table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642087/calculating-a-weighted-mean-using-data-table-in-r-with-weights-in-one-of-the-tab?rq=1)
In my case, I have different weights-columns across the columns I want to aggregate. Let's say I have four columns `col_a, col_b, col_c` and `col_d` and let's assume I want to aggregate `col_a` and `col_b` with weiths `w_1` and `col_c`, `col_d` with `w_2`. Example:

```
require(data.table)
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
col_a <- c(123,56,87,987,1003,10)
col_b <- c(17,234,20,88,765,69)
col_c <- c(45,90,543,30,1,543)
col_d <- c(60,43,700,3,88,46)
w_1   <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
w_2   <- c(1.5,1,1.2,0.8,1,1)
dt <- data.table(id, col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, w_1, w_2);dt
```

Now the desired result would look like this:

```
data.table(id=c(1,2),col_a=c(weighted.mean(col_a[1:3],w_1[1:3]),weighted.mean(col_a[4:6],w_1[4:6])),col_b=c(weighted.mean(col_b[1:3],w_1[1:3]),weighted.mean(col_b[4:6],w_1[4:6])),
       col_c=c(weighted.mean(col_c[1:3],w_2[1:3]),weighted.mean(col_c[4:6],w_1[4:6])),col_d=c(weighted.mean(col_d[1:3],w_2[1:3]),weighted.mean(col_d[4:6],w_2[4:6])))
```

This, I thought could be accomplished similar to @akrun answer to this post:
[R collapse multiple rows into 1 row using specific function to each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228200/r-collapse-multiple-rows-into-1-row-using-specific-function-to-each-column)
where I would have the two functions `weighted.mean(x, w_1)` and `weighted.mean(x, w_2)` instead of `min` or `median`. 
Here is how far I got:

```
colsToKeep <- c("col_a","col_b","col_c","col_d")
dt[, Map(function(x,y) get(x)(y, na.rm = TRUE), 
         setNames(rep(c('weighted.mean', 'weighted.mean'),2),names(.SD)), .SD),.SDcols=colsToKeep, by = id]
```

My question: how can get the arguments `w=w_1` and `w=w_2` into the `setNames`-function? Is that even possible?

Comment: Reshape your data to long format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be something like this too:

```
colsToKeep <- c("col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d")
colsToW <- c("w_1", "w_1", "w_2", "w_2")

eval(parse(text = paste0("dt[, .(", paste0("w_", colsToKeep, " = weighted.mean(", colsToKeep, ",", colsToW, ")", collapse = ", "), "), by = id]")))
```

Comment: This actually came closest to what I was looking for. I assume there was a reason why the lengthier solution was given by @chinsoon12 and casting the data to a more appropriate format might by the better way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

or this one:

```
dt[, Map(function(x,y,w) get(x)(y, w, na.rm = TRUE), 
         setNames(rep('weighted.mean',length(colsToKeep)), paste0("W_", colsToKeep)),
         .SD[, ..colsToKeep], .SD[, ..colsToW]),
   by = id]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Roland, you can cast into a long format. The benefit is that in the long run, you do not have to change the codes every time when there is a new column. Explanation in line. You can print `mdt` to take a look.

```
#cast into a long format with col values in 1 column and rows in another columns
mdt <- melt(dt, id.var=c("id",grep("^w", names(dt), value=TRUE)), 
    variable.name="col", value.name="colVal")
mdt <- melt(mdt, id.var=c("id","col","colVal"), 
    variable.name="w", value.name="wVal")

#prob need to think of a programmatic way rather than typing columns
myPairs <- data.table(rbind(
    c(col="col_a", w="w_1"), 
    c(col="col_b", w="w_1"), 
    c(col="col_c", w="w_2"), 
    c(col="col_d", w="w_2")))

#calculate weighted mean according to myPairs and then pivot the table
dcast(mdt[myPairs, on=.(col, w),
        weighted.mean(colVal, wVal), 
        by=.(id, col)], 
    id ~ col, 
    value.var="V1")
```